# How would you cross reference string variables for two ArrayLists to return the objects for those strings?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have two Arraylists of the objects:

```
Node(int id, String name, double pValue)
```

and

```
Edge(String node1, String node2, String type)
```

However in order to add an edge to my graph, the code goes something like:

```
main.addEdge(Edge e, Node n1, Node n2)
```

So as such, I'm using an interator to add the edges:

```
Iterator<Edge> eIt = edges.iterator();
   while(eIt.hasNext()){

     Node n1, n2;

     n1 = ?; //Code in question

     n2 = ?; //And here too

     mainGraph.addEdge(eIt.next(), n1, n2);
  }
```

How can I cross reference `eIt.next().getNode1()` / `getNode2()` with the ArrayList containing the nodes so that it would return the object Node with the matching name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description of your data structures, you have to iterate over the entire `Node` list to find the two nodes of the requested names.

You can make the search more efficient if you maintain a `HashMap<String,Node>` that gives you a `Node` by its name. However, that's really unnecessary.

Instead, I would suggest that your `Edge` class hold references to its two `Node`s instead of the names of those Nodes. Not only would it require less storage, it would also prevent the need to search for a Node by name.

Change your Edge to :

```
Edge(Node node1, Node node2, String type)
```

Then you code would be as simple as :

```
Iterator<Edge> eIt = edges.iterator();
 while(eIt.hasNext()){
    Edge e = eIt.next();
    mainGraph.addEdge(e, e.getNode1(), e.getNode2()); // actually, you can change
                                                      // addEdge to require just
                                                      // the Edge, since it already
                                                      // contains the Nodes
}
```

Comment: Ah I'd love it to be so, unfortunately the edges themselves are imported from files, and so they are only given string names. Sorry, I should have specified that in the question I guess.

Comment: @Talex In that case, when you import the Nodes, create a `HashMap<String,Node>`, and that would allow you to locate the 
Nodes by Name easily. I would still change the Edge class to hold references to the Nodes, though. This way you'll only need the Map when reading the data from the files.